# Changing disabled target of shortcuts

Tags: shortcut

The shortcut of a tool open the URL https://URL1.com
I want to change the target of the shortcut to https://URL2.com
Target is disabled (greyed). 
Does anyone know how I can change it so that the shortcut point on the URL2?

Comment: This question is an information vacuum. We're talking about a website? You're seeing `<a href="https://URL1.com">` in the source of the website? Do you need to edit the website itself? Or are you looking to just do it as one off? What limitations are there for the solution, can you just open the Dev Tools an edit it inline? Why does the URL need to change? Why can't you just go to the URL? Please update the question.

Comment: It about the target of the shortcut. When I open the shortcut it open the URL1 I want just to change the target and force it to URL2.